# Como devuelvo valores dentro de un switch

Tags: c

Hola soy nuevo en esto de código y trato de hacer un cajero automático.El cual me pida la contraseña en un inicio (esta la decido yo antes de iniciar), después me de 3 opciones salir,depositar o retira y todo parece ir bien hasta.  realizar una segunda acción dentro del case del switch el cual no me regresa un valor que pueda usar nuevamente en el switch para hacer otra acción (Volver a retirar,depositar o salirme) dejo el programa.Espero su ayuda gracias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 int password,deposit,retirement,money,out,choose;
 bool menu = false;

 money = 10000;


main(){

   do{
      money = money;
      printf(" Password:  ");
      scanf("%d", & password);

    if(password == 1234 ){
      vmenu();
      }
    else{
     system("cls");
     printf("\nIncorrect Password");
    }

      switch(choose){
       case 1:
        system("cls");
        printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
        printf("\n Introduce your deposit:  ");
        scanf("%d", & deposit);
        money = money + deposit;
        printf("\n Actual money:  %d",money);
        printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d", & choose);
       case 2:
        system("cls");
        printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
        printf("\n Introduce your retirement:  ");
        scanf("%d", & retirement);
        if(retirement>money){
          printf("Out of money");
          printf("\n Introduce your retirement:  ");
          scanf("%d", & retirement);
        }else if(retirement<money){
        money = money - retirement;
        printf("\n Actual money:  %d",money);
        printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d", & choose);
        }
       case 3:
        system("cls");
        printf("GRACIAS POR USARLO,VUELVA PRONTO");
        exit(1);
     }
   }
   while(!menu);
}

void vmenu(){
      money = money;
      system("cls");
      printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
      printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
      printf("\n");
      scanf("%d", & choose);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando a un `switch` se le pasa un valor, se salta a la etiqueta `case` que corresponda a dicho valor y sigue la ejecución linealmente hasta salir del `switch`, por lo tanto, si en tu código paso `choose` como `1`:

```
  switch(choose){
   case 1:
    system("cls");
    printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
    printf("\n Introduce your deposit:  ");
    scanf("%d", & deposit);
    money = money + deposit;
    printf("\n Actual money:  %d",money);
    printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", & choose);
   case 2:
    system("cls");
    printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
    printf("\n Introduce your retirement:  ");
    scanf("%d", & retirement);
    if(retirement>money){
      printf("Out of money");
      printf("\n Introduce your retirement:  ");
      scanf("%d", & retirement);
    }else if(retirement<money){
    money = money - retirement;
    printf("\n Actual money:  %d",money);
    printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", & choose);
    }
   case 3:
    system("cls");
    printf("GRACIAS POR USARLO,VUELVA PRONTO");
    exit(1);
 }
```

Se ejecutará todo lo que haya bajo el `case 1:`, seguidamente todo lo del `case 2:` y para acabar todo lo del `case 3:`, si quieres evitar eso, debes usar `break;` al final de las ordenes de cada `case`:

```
  switch(choose){
   case 1:
    system("cls");
    printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
    printf("\n Introduce your deposit:  ");
    scanf("%d", & deposit);
    money = money + deposit;
    printf("\n Actual money:  %d",money);
    printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", & choose);
    break; // <--- No sigas hacia el case 2
   case 2:
    system("cls");
    printf(" Balance:  %d",money);
    printf("\n Introduce your retirement:  ");
    scanf("%d", & retirement);
    if(retirement>money){
      printf("Out of money");
      printf("\n Introduce your retirement:  ");
      scanf("%d", & retirement);
    }else if(retirement<money){
    money = money - retirement;
    printf("\n Actual money:  %d",money);
    printf("\n\n Deposit press 1  \n Retirement press 2  \n Exit press 3");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", & choose);
    }
    break; // <--- No sigas hacia el case 3
   case 3:
    system("cls");
    printf("GRACIAS POR USARLO,VUELVA PRONTO");
    exit(1);
    break;
 }
```

Si lo que quieres es repetir el código del `switch` hasta que la opción sea la tercera, enciérralo en un bucle:

```
while(1) {
    switch(choose){
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Justo añade la variable return (); justo arriba del } de finalización de el switch.
La variable return devuelve el proceso de la clase cuando esta finaliza. Se basa en un bucle constante.

Comment: Si escribe `return` en `main`: finaliza el programa.

Comment: 5 veces lo he releído ... y aún no entiendo *na* :-(

Comment: Es lo que sucede con el agua, que moja y está húmeda. *Be water, mon amie*.